# Invalid parameter in Form Authentication Reporting Service SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am getting following error whenever I try to log on to Reporting Services:

> An error occurred while attempting to get the ReportServer Url. Invalid parameter.

What is the cause and how can solve the problem?

I was trying to follow steps from https://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com.

Thank you.

Comment: Anyone have some other solution other than this? I have been stuck at this point for weeks. I am greatly appreciated for your help. So far I haven't found any proper solution on net.

Comment: I am told it is because of report server is not configured well. and we have to give proper value for report server tag https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c861c5e2-c1a7-4d4c-b0d7-b77395b139b5/an-error-occurred-while-attempting-to-get-the-reportserver-url-invalid-namespace?forum=sqlreportingservices But I am still having this error although I changed those tags correctly. Any idea???

Comment: Hi I am suspecting that the program( maybe SQL server or .NET) can't read the server name, whether it contained RS_ or not.